# $F[x]/(p(x))$ contains the roots of $p(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-congruences

The following theorem and exercise are from "Abstract Algebra, An Introduction, 3rd Edition, Thomas W. Hungerford"

> #### Corollary 4.19
>
> Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x) \in F[x]$ be a polynomial of degree 2 or 3. Then $f(x)$ is irreducible if and only if f(x) has no roots in $F$.

> #### Exercise 5.3.8
>
> Let $F$ be a field. If $p(x)$ is an irreducible quadratic polynomial in $F[x]$, show that $F[x]/(p(x))$ contains all the roots of $p(x)$

This is highly confusing to me. If $p(x)$ is irreducible and quadratic, then it has no roots. So there is nothing to prove. On the other hand, if we see $p$ as $p: F[x]/(p(x)) \to F[x]/(p(x))$, then obviously all the roots of $p(x)$ are in $F[x]/(p(x))$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that the class of $p$ is zero in $F[x]/(p)$ by definition of the quotient ring. The Corollary has nothing to do with the Exercise. Take an example, e.g., $F=\Bbb Q$ and $p=x^2-2$. Then $F[x]/(p)\cong \Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: In general, as you know, given a polynomial $f(t)$ we say that $\alpha$ is a root if $f(\alpha) = 0$. Is there any element $\alpha \in \frac{F[x]}{p(x)}$ such that $p(\alpha) = 0$? Hint: It is the obvious one

Comment: @Dylan p([x]) = 0 is clear to me. I just don't understand the point of this fact. Let $K = F[x]/p(x)$. We are seeing $p$ as a function $p :K \to K$, right? $K$ is an extension field of $F$. Clearly, if $[g(x)]$ is a root of $p$, then $[g(x)] \in K$. I mean, what else? That is the domain of $p$.

Comment: @Dylan I'm aware that there is a hole in my understanding. I'm just trying to figure out where it is :). Do you know of a counter example of this?

Comment: @JustANoob Okay sure, so $p:K \rightarrow K$, and we know that $p([x]) = 0$, and you agree that this is obvious... "I just don't understand the point of this fact." -  I agree (or at least did when I first learnt this), it's so obvious it seems useless - but it's not! This says that $[x]$ is a root of $p$. So $p(X) = X^2 +bX + c = (X-x)(X-y)$ where $y$ is the other root. We see by comparing coefficients that $y = -b-x$ is the other root

Comment: @JustANoob by the way, do not feel bad if this doesn't make sense/feels wrong/feels too obvious to be right. The main takeaway of this exercise and something you will get used to when working in these quotient rings is getting away from the fact that roots of polynomials are "numbers", I mean, up to now a root of a polynomial was something like $2$, or $\sqrt{2}$ or maybe even $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$, but here we are saying that $x$ is a root (and it really is, we have seen it, and it has as much of a right to be a root as $2$ or $4$ or any other number does).

Comment: @Dylan For now, I just see the statement of the exercise equivalent to this (seeing $\mathbb{C}$ as an extension of $\mathbb{R}$): Let $f \to \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $f_E : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be an extension of $f$. Clearly, $f(x) = 0 \implies f_E(x) = 0$. I'll keep on reading on this subject. As for now, this exercise remains useless to me.

Comment: @Dylan If you know an example of $p$ where this does not hold, please provide one. It might clear this mystery for me :)

Comment: @JustANoob Good idea, if $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $p(X) = X^3 - 2$ then let's check if all roots of $p$ are in $K = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(p(x))}$. Again we have the obvious fact that $[x] \in K$ is a root, since $p([x]) = 0$. What about the other roots? Here I want to be careful not to write nonsense, in order to find the other roots let's move to an extension $K(\sqrt{3}i)$ of $K$ (if this isn't clear, just think that we want to think of finding roots of $p$ in $\mathbb{C}$). Then the other roots are $x\omega$ and $x\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a $3^{rd}$ root of unity.

Comment: ...We have $\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}$, however $\sqrt{3}i \notin \mathbb{Q}$ so $x\omega, x\omega^2 \notin K$. So all roots of $p$ are not in $K$.

Comment: @Dylan I'll digest your example and come back to you. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Dylan I think I know where the confusion comes from, correct me if I'm wrong. The thing in question is: If $K_e$ is an extended field of $K$, does $K$ contain all the roots of $p: K_e \to K_e$? The result of the exercise is that this indeed guaranteed under given conditions. i.e. we can't generate more roots by extending the field $K$. This is indeed not obvious at all.

Comment: @JustANoob Yea exactly, if $p$ is irreducible quadratic then $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ contains all it's roots, and we don't need to extend $\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$ to a bigger field. As you say this is not always the case, maybe the easiest example of this is $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, as we know the roots of this polynomial do not live in $\mathbb{R}$ - in fact the (smallest) field you need to extend to the find the roots is $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+1)} \cong \mathbb{R}(i) \cong \mathbb{C}.$

Answer (score 1):

Although $p(x)$ does not have roots in $F$, it may have roots in a larger field $F'$ containing $F$.

What they're asking you to show is that $F'=\dfrac{F[t]}{\langle p(t)\rangle}$ is a field with elements $k_1,k_2,k_3$ such that $p(x)=k_3(x-k_1)(x-k_2)$.

Comment: What is wrong with this "logic":  Let $r \in F[x]/p(x)$ be a root of $p(x)$. Then $r \in  F[x]/p(x)$....

Comment: @JustANoob That is why I used $t$ in $F'=\dfrac{F[t]}{\langle p(t)\rangle}$, not to get mixed up with $x$

Comment: Do you know of an example where this does not hold? e.g a field $F$ with $p(x) \in F[x]$ such that a root of $p(x)$ is not contained in $F[x]/p(x) ? $

Answer (score 0):

In $A =F[x]/I$ with $I=\langle p(x)\rangle$ take the residue class $\overline x=x+I$ of $x$.

Then $p(\overline x)=p(x+I) =p(x)+I = I =0+I =\overline 0$ as claimed.